# Tracking Pixel in 'flash-message'

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a website where after the user has made a successful payment, they are returned to their account page with a **flash message** - *Transaction is completed successfully* displayed along the top. Is it possible to place a tracking pixel (for Facebook and/or Google) in this **flash message**?

If it is possible what would I need to add to the code below to add a Facebook tracking pixel?

```
$this->session->set_flashdata(
    'flash_message',
    $this->common_model->flash_message(
        'success',
        $this->lang->line(
            'Transaction is completed successfully'
        )
    )
);
```

I hope this is clear and thanks in advance for any advice.

Thanks for the answer below but it is a bit more complicated with Facebook, you are supposed to add a the piece of code below to the 'Successful Transaction Landing Page' but in this case it is just a 'flash message that is displayed.

```
<!-- Facebook Conversion Code for Facebook cpa -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var fb_param = {};
fb_param.pixel_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX';
fb_param.value = '0.01';
fb_param.currency = 'USD';
(function(){
var fpw = document.createElement('script');
fpw.async = true;
fpw.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fp.js';
var ref = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
ref.parentNode.insertBefore(fpw, ref);
})();
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none"                            
 src="https://www.facebook.com/offsite_event.php?        
 id=xxxxxxxxxx&amp;value=0.01&amp;currency=USD" /></noscript>
```

Thanks again

Hi again thanks for the reply. I have eventually tried to implement the above code but unfortunately the tracking pixel is not being passed into the displayed flash message. Any further suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, try something like this:

```
$trackingCode = '<!-- Facebook Conversion Code for Facebook cpa -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var fb_param = {};
fb_param.pixel_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
fb_param.value = "0.01";
fb_param.currency = "USD";
(function(){
var fpw = document.createElement("script");
fpw.async = true;
fpw.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fp.js";
var ref = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
ref.parentNode.insertBefore(fpw, ref);
})();
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none"                            
 src="https://www.facebook.com/offsite_event.php?        
 id=xxxxxxxxxx&amp;value=0.01&amp;currency=USD" /></noscript>';

$this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', $this->common_model->flash_message('success',$this->lang->line('Transaction is completed successfully').$trackingCode));
```

It will append $trackingCode to the translated line. Please mind that I've changed all single quotes (`'`) to double quotes (`"`) to prevent syntax errors and unnecessary escaping.

The second argument in `->flash_message` is just the string you want to have displayed. Whether it is just a string or Javascript, that doesn't matter.